# VSCode SCSS extension with better error checking

Tags: visual-studio-code, sass, error-checking

I recently started writing SCSS in VSCode. VSCode itself along with vscode-scss extension provides relatively good support for SCSS, but an important feature seems missing - error checking.
Though VSCode and vscode-scss can offer suggestions through Intellisense based on scanning, no errors will be prompted if I misspelled a variable, or used a mixin that hadn't been imported yet. Also, no auto refactoring takes place after renaming an SCSS file that has been used by other sources.
Is there any VSCode extension that provides such validations? Or maybe they can be turned on through some options in extension settings?
Note: I do have noticed the `scss.showErrors` option of vscode-scss, but no errors get prompted in scenarios mentioned above after turning this option on.

Comment: never to late to add this to the extension yourself

Comment: Thats why I use prepos as a compiler. Immediately shows your errors

Comment: @rioV8 haha, good point, but the missing of these features still makes me wonder, since these are very common scenarios, and I can't be the only one being bothered.

Comment: set up a watch task that transpiles your scss and add a problem matcher